# Runtime optimization for regular expression

Tags: regex, go

Most regular expression is "constant" in their life time.  Is it a good idea to use **global** regular expression to speed up execution?  For example:

```
func work() {
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`...`)
    if r.MatchString(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

comparing with:

```
var r *regexp.Regexp

func work() {
    if r.MatchString(...) {
        ...
    }
}

func init() {
    r = regexp.MustCompile(`...`)
}
```

Do these 2 versions has any meaningful difference?

1. Regular expression compiling is so cheap so that it is not worth to use global regex, both in term of CPU cost and garbage collecting (suppose `work()` is heavily called)
2. It is better to use global regular expression whenever approriate.

Which of the above is correct, or the answer is not simply black/white?

Comment: Use a single statement to declare and initialize the package-level variable: `var r = regexp.MustCompile(\`...\`)`.

Comment: Regardless of performance considerations, if the regexp is totally under your control (as opposed to being user-specified) and happens to be malformed, would you not want execution to fail as soon as possible, i.e. at package initialisation rather than at the first call of your `work` function? The answer to this question should guide your decision to declare the regexp at package level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use same regular expression(eg "`\d+`") just once -> it is not worth to use global regex.

if you use same regular expression(eg "`\d+`") often -> it is worth to use

```
func Benchmark01(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        r := regexp.MustCompile(`\d+`)
        r.MatchString("aaaaaaa123bbbbbbb")
    }
}

func Benchmark02(b *testing.B) {
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`\d+`)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        r.MatchString("aaaaaaa123bbbbbbb")
    }
}
```

```
Benchmark01
Benchmark01-4             886909              1361 ns/op
Benchmark02
Benchmark02-4            5368380               232.8 ns/op
```